# How do I throttle my iAd loading?

Tags: iphone, ios, iad

I keep getting this error:

> Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Loading throttled" UserInfo=0x6a6bf50 {ADInternalErrorCode=2, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Loading throttled}

How do I throttle my loading? The application I am making is relatively small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this for an App still in development?  Apple purposely sends you errors to make sure you handle them properly - throttled loading is one of those errors.  If you sometimes get content and sometimes don't then that's normal.

Comment: OMG, Apple should warn us about this! Thanks for the info!

Comment: They do... "To assist you in validating your implementation, the iAd Network occasionally returns errors to test your error handling code."  - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/TestingiAdApplications/TestingiAdApplications.html  - I just think their concept of 'occasionally' is different from most peoples...