# More than 1 AdbannerViews

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, iad, adbannerview

Im having a little problem with `ADBanner`'s, I have 3 `UIViewController`'s and each one have an `ADBanner`. I have set up the delegate methods like this:

```
-(void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner {
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:nil];
banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, 320);
[UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:nil];
banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, 320+banner.frame.size.height);
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

In every `UIViewController` class file, Im using `UIStoryboard`. The delegate is connected properly.

**Now the issue.**

In the initial `ViewController` the `ADBanner` loads like it should, but when I click it it the ad loads in fullscreen, but when I click the x button to get out of the ad I get an error from the `didFailToReceiveAdWithError` saying: `NSLocalizedFailureReason=Loading throttled` and the `ADBanner` disappears. This error happens for every `ADBanner`. There is 1 more strange thing happening. If I dont click the ad in the initial `ViewController` the `ADBanners` in the other 2 `ViewControllers` the ad doesnt load and gives me the same error from above but 2 times. If i click and dissmisses the `ADBanner` in the initial `ViewController` the other 2 loads without an error, but the one in the initial does.

To make it short, when the initial `ViewControllers` `ADBanner` loads the other 2 dont, and when the other 2 loads the initial doesnt
Why is this happening I find this very weird. I read the documentations but I didnt find anything if there was a limit of `ADBanners` you can have.

Comment: Do you get any other errors?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572681/how-do-i-throttle-my-iad-loading) Apple sends this error on purpose. They do that to make sure you can handle the error properly. Also you should not be creating separate iAds but using 1 in all view controllers. Please read this  [article](http://stevemoser.org/blog/2013/04/24/how-to-create-a-shared-iad-banner-in-a-tabbed-application-with-storyboards/) on how to create shared iAds.

Comment: I want to remove or hide the ad in some viewcontrollers so that wont work, I dont know how to do it.

Comment: @Arbitur Try setting the hidden property to YES

Comment: But wont apple prevent me from doing it? maybe when they check it before adding it to appstore?

Comment: @Arbitur Or you could set the alpha to zero

Comment: @Arbitur I do not think Apple would prevent you from doing this.... You should look in the documentation.