# Implementing iAd in Cocos2d V3 with MyiAd

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, iad

I downloaded [iAd Banner Sample for cocos2d V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842944/ios-7-iad-cocos2d-deprecated/21845349#21845349). Thanks so much for that code. The demo works fine and needs the user to tap Show Ad or Hide Ad button. Of course in my game I do not want the player to tap a button to Show Ads. In IntroScene.m I commented out the code that creates the buttons and added these lines at the end of init:

```
AppDelegate * app = (((AppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate));    
[app ShowIAdBanner];
```

This is the same code that would have been executed if the Show Ad button had been pressed. I expected to see an ad without having to tap a button. However, I got no ad. I got the following error message in the log:

> ADBannerView: Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not
>   implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain
>   Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Loading throttled"

There is -(void)bannerDidFail method in AppDelegate. It works by tapping button. How do I get the ads to show up automatically, without tapping a button first? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I throttle my iAd loading?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572681/how-do-i-throttle-my-iad-loading)

Comment: I think this is different. If I leave the buttons in place, but put in the code to go directly to ShowIAdBanner, I get the error in the log and the demo just hangs. I can tap the button and get an ad. It seems to be in an infinite loop if I don't use the button. Also, an alert should pop up if there is an error -- it does not. The alert does pop up if there is an error after a button tap.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to tell you exactly what is happening. Make sure that you have the following line:

bannerView.delegate = self; //bannerView is an object of type AdBannerView* that you created before

Check also that the class where the previous line is, implements the method:

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error

I recently wrote a tutorial on integrating iAds in Cocos2d-x v3. Although the language is different (C++ instead of Objective-C), the procedure and syntax are rather similar: http://becomingindiedev.blogspot.com.es/2015/02/integrating-iad-in-cocos2d-x-v3x.html